# Mostrar la variable con su valor diferente

Tags: java, jsp

Buen día, Tengo una duda estoy generando este ciclo:

```
 while (rs.next()) 
        {
            num1 = rs.getInt(1);
            texto1 = rs.getString(2);
            texto2=rs.getString(3);

        }
```

input1 = num1(primer valor)
input2 = num1(segundo valor)
input3 = num1(tercer valor)
input4 = texto1(primer valor)
input5 = texto1(segundo valor)
input6 = texto 1(tercer valor)

Entonces son tres variables que van a tener tres valores ni mas ni menos.
¿Es posible mostrar esa variable en tres input diferentes osea su valor?
Normalmente retorno las variables con json

Comment: ¿Quieres mostrar num1 en un input, text1 en otro y texto2 en otro input? Si es así, ya tienes todo, solo tienes que asignar la variable que quieres al valor del input donde quieres mostrarlo, o mejor aún, asignara al valor del input directamente del json que retornas.

Comment: Puedes explicar mejor lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: Depende de qué inputs de donde vayas a usarlo.
Es en android, es tueditText.setText(texto1)
Ten cuidado que si es un int tienes que poner: String.valueof(num1)

Comment: Si pero a lo que me refiero es que esa variable traerá 3 valores cada una, entonces por cada valor quiero mostrarlo en un input diferente

Comment: Una variable no puede tener 3 valores.Tiene uno solo. Lo que vos pensas que esta pasando, en realidad no esta pasando. En cada vuelta a tu recordset, las variables estan tomando ese valor, y descartan los otros. Si quisieras devolver todos los valores, tendrias que generar una lista o una lista de clases o una coleccion o algun objeto que te permita devolver todos los valores.

Comment: Bueno entonces si genero una variable por cada valor que resulto ¿podría hacer lo que quiero cierto?

Comment: @DavidMelo no se que es lo que pensas hacer, pero deberias revisar conceptos de variables y guardado de datos. Lo que estas diciendo no tiene sustento. Que pasa si en lugar de tres son 5 las vueltas?

Comment: Bueno entonces ¿como puedo mostrar cada vuelta?

Comment: Puedes meter cada vuelta en un array de dos dimensiones de esta forma sabes en que orden las cogiste y puedes gestionarlo a tu antojo

Por ejemplo:

arrayPosicion0 a los input 1, 2, 3

arrayPosicion1 a los input 4, 5, 6

Comment: Excelente, gracias por su ayuda me funciono el consejo